# Optionally create relationship in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to build a Cypher query which will connect an actor to the movie, or update existing relationship with new values of relationship property. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
MATCH (actor:Person{name:"Tom Hanks"})
MATCH (movie:Movie{title:"Cloud Atlas"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (actor)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(movie)
SET r.roles = ['Role 1', 'Role 2']
```

This works fine for the actors and movies which came from the example in Neo4j and are already connected, but not when I try to create new relationship, because `r` is null and cannot be updated.

So, how can I update `r.roles` if the relationship `r` exists or create a new relationship if it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `MERGE`, which creates a pattern if it doesn't exist, otherwise it is retrieved:

```
MATCH (actor:Person{name:"Tom Hanks"})
MATCH (movie:Movie{title:"Cloud Atlas"})
MERGE (actor)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(movie)
SET r.roles = ['Role 1', 'Role 2']
```

You should also [check out](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html#_use_on_create_and_on_match) `ON CREATE SET` and `ON MATCH SET`, which will allow you to do different things depending on if the pattern was created or retrieved:

```
MATCH (actor:Person{name:"Tom Hanks"})
MATCH (movie:Movie{title:"Cloud Atlas"})
MERGE (actor)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(movie)
    ON MATCH SET r.roles = ['Role 1', 'Role 2']
    ON CREATE SET r.roles = ['Role 3', 'Role 4']
```

Comment: Some slick stuff here! Didn't know we could do different actions in different cases! Thanks Nicole, works like a charm :)